# pdfmake.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, pdfmake

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null

when running the next html/javascript code on my client machine, but it works on playground, but i dont know what the error is.

PLAYGROUND: http://pdfmake.org/playground.html

```
<html> <head>
<title>Ingreso Simple</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.20/pdfmake.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.20/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
</head> <body> <script>
var usuario = 'user';
var left = 25;
var right = 25;
var top = 290;
var bottom = 50;


var dd = {
    // a string or { width: number, height: number }
    pageSize: 'LETTER',

    // by default we use portrait, you can change it to landscape if you wish
    pageOrientation: 'portrait',

    // [left, top, right, bottom] or [horizontal, vertical] or just a number for equal margins
    pageMargins: [left, top, right, bottom],
    footer: function (currentPage, pageCount) {
        return {
            margin: [25,10,0,0],
            text:currentPage.toString() + ' / ' + pageCount};
    },
    fontSize: 9,
    header: {
        margin: [0,25,25,25],
        fontSize: 9,
        stack: [
            {columns: [
                {text: ' ', width:150},
                {stack: [
                    {text: 'ASDASD',fontSize: 14},
                    {text: 'DGDFGDF',fontSize: 12},
                    {text: 'ASDA 225522',fontSize: 12}
                ]},
                {stack: [
                    {text: 'EMS',fontSize: 11},
                    {text: '22/02/2016',fontSize: 11},
                    {text: usuario, fontSize: 11}],
                    alignment: 'right',
                    width: 85
                }
            ]
            },
            {
                margin: [25, 15, 0, 0],
                columns: ['IMERC RECIB', {text: 'SIMPLE', alignment: 'right'}]
            },
            {
                margin: [25,0,0,0],
                columns:[
                    {text:[{text:'Descargado por: ',bold:true}, 'Cliente']},
                    {text:[{text:'Mercaderia Paletizada? ',bold:true}, 'Granel']},
                    {text:[{text:'Utiliza DAN? ',bold:true}, 'SI']}
                ]
            },
            {
                margin: [25,0,0,0],
                columns:[
                    {text:[{text:'Bulks Armados: ',bold:true}, '7.0'], width:95},
                    {text:[{text:'Bulks Flejados: ',bold:true}, '7.0'], width:95},
                    {text:[{text:'Area ocupada: ',bold:true}, '19.0 m²']},
                    {text:[{text:'Volumen ocupado: ',bold:true}, '37.0 m³']},
                    {text:[{text:'Peso kilogramos: ',bold:true}, '3200.0']}
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    content: [
        {
            fontSize: 9,
            table:{
                headerRows:1,
                widths: [ 60, 60, 145, 135, 55, 55 ],
                body:[
                    [
                        'Codigo 1',
                        'Codigo 2',
                        'Descripcion Mercaderia',
                        {stack:['$$%%%', {columns:['Dec', 'Rec', 'Dif']}],alignment: 'center'},
                        'UM',
                        'EM'
                    ],[
                        '10094461 2',
                        ' ',
                        'Exhividres de mesa',
                        {stack:[{columns:['0','0','0']}]},
                        'BTOS',
                        'Resellado'
                    ],[
                        '10094461 2',
                        ' ',
                        'Exhividres de mesa',
                        {stack:[{columns:['0','0','0']}]},
                        'BTOS',
                        'Roto'
                    ],
                    [' ',' ', ' ', {stack:[{columns:['2222','3232','2']}]}, ' ',' ']]
            }
        },
        {margin:[0,10,0,0], text:[{text:'Observaciones: ', bold:true}, 'ASDASDASDAS']},
        {margin:[0,20,0,0], stack:[
            {columns:['CLIENTE', {text:' ',width:50}, 'Recibe Mercaderia']},
            {columns:['Entrega de Mercaderia', {text:' ',width:50}, 'Jefe de Bodega']},
            {columns:['M1212121 _____________________', {text:' ',width:50}, 'Milton Marroquin _____________________']},
            {columns:[' ', {text:'SELLO',width:50}, ' ']},
            {columns:['Visto Bueno', {text:' ',width:50}, 'Fecha: _____________________']},
            {columns:['Jefe de Produccion', {text:' ',width:50}, 'Hora: _____________________']},
            {columns:['Ing. Roberto Estrada_____________________', {text:' ',width:50}, 'Funcionario de Aduana _____________________']}
        ]}
    ]
};
var asdf = pdfMake.createPdf(dd);
asdf.open(); </script> </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code is automatically trying to generate the PDF in a popup window. If the popup gets blocked, that causes errors to occur within the pdfmake script (which seems like a big problem on their part, that error should be handled quite a bit more gracefully than that)

I tried your code locally and it failed, but once I enabled popups, it worked as expected. I'm not sure if there's another way to use the library that doesn't rely on `window.open()`, but it might be worth looking into

The bit of problem code in pdfmake.js is here:

```
Document.prototype.open = function(message) {
    // we have to open the window immediately and store the reference
    // otherwise popup blockers will stop us
    var win = window.open('', '_blank');

    try {
        this.getDataUrl(function(result) {
            win.location.href = result;
        });
    } catch(e) {
        win.close();
        throw e;
    }
};
```

If you want a quick solution, download that script, host it locally, and change the above section to this:

```
Document.prototype.open = function(message) {
    // we have to open the window immediately and store the reference
    // otherwise popup blockers will stop us
    //var win = window.open('', '_blank');

    try {
        this.getDataUrl(function(result) {
          document.querySelector('iframe').src = result;
        });
    } catch(e) {
        win.close();
        throw e;
    }
};
```

Then you just need an iframe somewhere on your page, and you can swap `document.querySelector('iframe')` with a specific reference to that particular frame. It's still probably better to find a way to get it working without editing the include like that, but it at least proves that the popup is indeed the source problem.

Comment: @lennin92 I'm not sure what would still be causing the error. I copied your exact code sample into a local html file and it worked as expected. What happens if you log `asdf` to the console before attempting to call `asdf.open()`

Comment: @lennin92 I've also updated my answer to include a potential solution to the problem

Comment: @jmcgriz sure. its just my opinion. i did it from a review and to me it seemed more of a comment than a solution. It seems since then you have updated it a bunch to a much more clear answer with examples. Ill remove the review.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace fair enough, thanks. I was hesitant to provide that solution originally since modifying libraries is usually a bad idea, but it's the quickest way to get that code up and running.